# how can i allow url fopen on .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, php

i want to allow the url_fopen on the php.ini settings set to ON, but i dnt have access to this on a shared server, how can i use the .htaccess file to allow this to hapen, thanks :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your host disabled this for security reasons, then you likely cannot override it, as that would defeat the purpose of disabling it.

Comment: can you read this please, 1and1 hosting allows me to switch it on, but i just dnt know how!! http://faq.oneandone.co.uk/scripting/php/php5_upgrade/2.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change the values in your PHP code on the fly http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

I agree with @Dan Grossman though - be careful what you're changing.